# Create a Cookie Remembering if Page Should Load Mobile or Desktop Layout of a Responsive Design

Tags: javascript, mobile, cookies, responsive-design

I have created a responsive design that allows the user to switch between the mobile and desktop layouts. My only issue is that if a user wants to view the desktop version and then clicks another link, or refreshes the page, the mobile version is loaded again. I want to create a cookie so that it remember's the user's preference on each page load.

Here is the javascript I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.full_site').click(function() {
        $('body').removeClass('mobile');
        $('body').addClass('desktop');
        $('.views-row').each(function(i,e) {
            $('.content .body', e).insertAfter($('.content .loc-text', e));
        });
    });

    $('.mobile_site').click(function() {
        $('body').removeClass('desktop');
        $('body').addClass('mobile');
        $('.views-row').each(function(i,e) {
          $('.content .body', e).insertBefore($('.content .field-name-field-image-one', e));
        });

        $('.views-row').each(function(i,e) {
          $('.content .body', e).insertBefore($('.content .field-name-field-image', e));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So what problem are you having? Have you tried JQuery cookie plugin?

Comment: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: Hi Mike. I have not tried that plugin before, but it looks like it will do the trick. The problem is, I have never worked with cookeis before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a rough draft with comments included to help you through the process:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.full_site').click(function() {
        document.cookie = "type=full"; //set/update the cookie
        $('body').removeClass('mobile');
        $('body').addClass('desktop');
        $('.views-row').each(function(i,e) {
            $('.content .body', e).insertAfter($('.content .loc-text', e));
        });
    });

    $('.mobile_site').click(function() {
        document.cookie = "type=mobile"; //set/update cookie
        $('body').removeClass('desktop');
        $('body').addClass('mobile');
        $('.views-row').each(function(i,e) {
          $('.content .body', e).insertBefore($('.content .field-name-field-image-one', e));
        });

        $('.views-row').each(function(i,e) {
          $('.content .body', e).insertBefore($('.content .field-name-field-image', e));
        });
    });
   if(/*check to see what the cookie is...*/) 
     $(".mobile_site").trigger("click"); //trigger the mobile site
   else
     $(".full_site").trigger("click"); //trigger the full site
});
```

More about cookies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie

and: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help! Worked perfectly. I need to do more research on cookies.

Comment: Glad I could help. You may be interested in the 3 functions noted here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html `getCookie`, `setCookie` and `eraseCookie`. No sense in "reinventing the wheel" and it may help you out a bit.

Comment: Hey Chase. I'm having an odd issue with this right now. When I have if(document.cookie.type == "mobile") or if(document.cookie.type == "full", the page automatically loads the full version. If I click mobile, it load the mobile version, but then reverts back to the full version if I reload the page or go to a new page. Any ideas? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: My apologies. I had removed that line yesterday because you can not access the type that way. In my previous comment I mentioned 3 functions that should be of some assistance for getting, setting and clearing a cookie. Please have a look at them and include them in your code. If you still need any help then let me know. And again, it was my mistake, you can not use `document.cookie.type` because `document.cookie` is a string and not an object.